# Should work but doesn't work this NFC code

Tags: android, nfc

I have this code in my Main activity. In this activity I write data to NFC tag. This work perfectly:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private NfcAdapter mAdapter;
private boolean mInWriteMode;
private Button mWriteTagButton;
private TextView mTextView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    // grab our NFC Adapter
    mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

    // button that starts the tag-write procedure
    mWriteTagButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.write_tag_button);
    mWriteTagButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    // TextView that we'll use to output messages to screen
    mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.write_tag_button) {
        displayMessage("Touch and hold tag against phone to write.");
        enableWriteMode();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    disableWriteMode();
}

/**
 * Called when our blank tag is scanned executing the PendingIntent
 */
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    if(mInWriteMode) {
        mInWriteMode = false;

        // write to newly scanned tag
        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        writeTag(tag);
    }
}

/**
 * Force this Activity to get NFC events first
 */
private void enableWriteMode() {
    mInWriteMode = true;

    // set up a PendingIntent to open the app when a tag is scanned
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
    IntentFilter[] filters = new IntentFilter[] { tagDetected };

    mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, filters, null);
}

private void disableWriteMode() {
    mAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
}

/**
 * Format a tag and write our NDEF message
 */
private boolean writeTag(Tag tag) {
    // record to launch Play Store if app is not installed
    NdefRecord appRecord = NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord(getPackageName());

    // record that contains our custom "retro console" game data, using custom MIME_TYPE
    byte[] payload = getRandomConsole().getBytes();
    byte[] mimeBytes = MimeType.NFC_DEMO.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
    NdefRecord cardRecord = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_MIME_MEDIA, mimeBytes, 
                                            new byte[0], payload);
    NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] { cardRecord, appRecord});

    try {
        // see if tag is already NDEF formatted
        Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
        if (ndef != null) {
            ndef.connect();

            if (!ndef.isWritable()) {
                displayMessage("Read-only tag.");
                return false;
            }

            // work out how much space we need for the data
            int size = message.toByteArray().length;
            if (ndef.getMaxSize() < size) {
                displayMessage("Tag doesn't have enough free space.");
                return false;
            }

            ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);
            displayMessage("Tag written successfully.");
            return true;
        } else {
            // attempt to format tag
            NdefFormatable format = NdefFormatable.get(tag);
            if (format != null) {
                try {
                    format.connect();
                    format.format(message);
                    displayMessage("Tag written successfully!\nClose this app and scan tag.");
                    return true;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    displayMessage("Unable to format tag to NDEF.");
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                displayMessage("Tag doesn't appear to support NDEF format.");
                return false;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        displayMessage("Failed to write tag");
    }

    return false;
}

private String getRandomConsole() {
    double rnd = Math.random();
    if(rnd<0.25) return "Random-1";
    else if(rnd<0.5) return "Random-2";
    else if(rnd<0.75) return "Random-3";
    else return "Random-4";
}

private void displayMessage(String message) {
    mTextView.setText(message);
}
```

}

Then, this is the activity where I read de data from NFC tag. Theoretically, when a NFC tag is discovered, this is the activity that the system launch but the system launch the previous activity. This is the code:

```
public class CardActivity extends Activity {
private TextView mCardView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.card_activity);

    // ImageView that we'll use to display cards
    mCardView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.card_view);

    // see if app was started from a tag and show game console
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent.getType() != null && intent.getType().equals(MimeType.NFC_DEMO)) {
        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = getIntent().getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        NdefMessage msg = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[0];
        NdefRecord cardRecord = msg.getRecords()[0];
        String consoleName = new String(cardRecord.getPayload());
        mCardView.setText(consoleName);
    }
}
```

}

The manifest file is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".CardActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.daggothSoft.nfcdemo"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

And the last activity with the MIME-Type is:

```
public class MimeType {
public static final String NFC_DEMO = "application/vnd.daggothSoft.nfcdemo";
```

}

The problem is that when I scan an NFC tag, the activity that launch the system isn't what it should according to the manifest. Always launch the Main activity. I don't know where is the problem, what is the problem and..... well, any comments or help will be very useful.

Thanks, really, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Watch out that Android's MIME type matching for intent filters is case-sensitive -- eventhough the MIME types themselves are not. Therefore, with Android (and also pretty much everywhere you use them) you should stick to the convention to use MIME types with lowercase letters only.

Specifically with MIME type records stored on NFC tags, Android will automatically convert them to all-lowercase letters to overcome the problem of case-sensitivity in intent filters. So in your example, changing the type name in the intent filter to `"application/vnd.daggothsoft.nfcdemo"` will work:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
    <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.daggothsoft.nfcdemo"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Then, you should also make sure you write the MIME type in lowercase letters only:

```
public static final String NFC_DEMO = "application/vnd.daggothsoft.nfcdemo";
```